# How to get Excel data row by row in a Python list

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I want to get data row by row in a python list from an excel file. For example, my excel file contains multiple rows of data and the first element of my python list will be a list that will contain all the information of the first row, the second element of the list will be a list that will contain the information of the second row of the excel file and so on.
Can anybody teach me the easiest way of doing that?
Thank you :)

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html
Once you have the dataframe, you can call df.values.tolist()

Answer (score 3):

If you are already using pandas, then this is relatively straightforward:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('book1.xlsx',engine='openpyxl',dtype=object,header=None)

print(df.head())

l = df.values.tolist()

print(l)
```

NB. You may have to `pip install openpyxl` if it is not already in your packages.

[Pandas read_excel documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

EDIT: You don't really need the `engine` and `dtype` parameters: pandas defaults to openpyxl if you specify ".xlsx", and you can let pandas handle the types in most circumstances.

The `header=None` is important though, otherwise pandas will interpret the first row of your Excel sheet as the dataframe column names.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be saving that excel file into a `CSV` and then loading it. The proprietary excel files would be hard to decode. Use `Save as...` and the option `CSV file`.

Then, do this:

```
filename = ...
rows = []
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        rows.append(line.split(","))
print(rows)
```

The advantage of this approach is that you need no external libraries to do this. It uses basic Python only.

Comment: Thank you but I am restricted to the excel file.

Comment: @MR.JD Unlucky. Pandas would be your best option then I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you list of list -

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')

l1 = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    l1.append(row.to_list())
```

Comment: what is 'test' here ?

Comment: @MR.JD It is most likely df.iterrows()

Answer (score 0):

Reading a given column of a sheet in a Workbook can be done like this:

```
    # required packages: pandas, openpyxl

    #--- import section -------------------------------------------------
    import pandas 

    #--- create file variable: ------------------------------------------

    my_excel_file = "my_file.xlsx"

    #--- create lists: --------------------------------------------------
    df = pandas.read_excel(my_excel_file, sheet_name='my_sheet')

    # with header:
    my_list = (list)(df["my_header"].values)

    # without header:
    my_second_list = (list)(df[df.columns[1]].values)

    #--- process list: --------------------------------------------------
    print(len(my_list))
    for my_item in my_list:
            print(my_item, end = "; ")
```